# Server-side validation in Android: asynchronous method called in if statement workaround

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, parse-platform

I was using the [Parse API](https://parse.com) and was trying to implement a change password feature when came across this issue.

I was trying to validate that the user's current password matches their *attempted current password* (what the user entered into the EditText).

Since **the Parse API, doesn't allow access to the user's encrypted password**, I'm validating that the user's input matches the current password by trying to log in with the *attempted current password* and username. If the log in was successful, then the *attempted current password* is correct.

When the change password button is clicked, I check if the *attempted current password* matches the actual current password:

```
if (mCurrentPassword != null && passwordsMatch(mCurrentPassword)) {
    mCurrentPasswordEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
}
```

I created a `passwordsMatch(String mAttemptedCurrentPassword)` method here:

```
private boolean passwordsMatch(String mCurrentPassword) {
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("username", mUser.getUsername());
    params.put( "attemptedCurrentPassword", mCurrentPassword);

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("validateMatchingPasswords", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
       public void done(Object o, ParseException e) {
           if (e == null) {
             // password match (success)
           } else {
             // password do not match (failure)
           }
       }
    });

}
```

The above code is incomplete. I have a cloud code function, which tries log the user in and responds with a success or error. I am having trouble finding a workaround because I don't understand threading that well.

How can I make the `if (passwordsMatch)` statement wait for the `passwordsMatch` method to get a result?

**Edit:**

For those unfamiliar to Parse, here is what the `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground` function is doing:

It is essentially an AsyncTask. It has a callback `FunctionCallback`, which implements the `done` method. The `done` method is called when `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground` returns a result. It's analogous to the `onPostExecute` method.

The problem is that I have to return a boolean after the asynchronous task is finished.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is make a server request (GET/POST) with a pair of username and password. You can use the following code

```
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>(){

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.urloflink.com");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>;
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "pass"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
 }
}

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     result = response.getresult(); // a hypothetical function according to your server response format
   // Extract response string from response and check the result
   if(result == "success"){
    // DO something
   }
   else if(result == "failure"){
    // Do something
   }
 }.execute();
```

This is an asynctask which runs in a separate thread. Hence during this process you can show processing ring or some animation. The content in doInBackground() runs in background and to make any changes to the UI you can use onPostExecute() block.

You can use the above code in your password match function as:

```
private boolean passwordsMatch(String mCurrentPassword) {

   new AsyncTask<String,....
    ....
   }.execute();
 }
```

Make sure that you replace the function response.getResult() with an actual function or some code segment that gives you the result.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! This `AsyncTask ` is essentially what the `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground` is already doing. It has a callback `FunctionCallback` which implements the `done` method. This method is called when the cloud code function returns a result. It's analogous to the `onPostExecute` method. The problem is that I have to return a boolean after the asynchronous task is finished. In your `passwordsMatch` method, how would you return a boolean from the `onPostExecute` method?

Comment: A global boolean variable could be used (false by default). When the server returns the result it can be set according to it and a function with boolean parameter could be called which does your remaining work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't do it this way. You may create a Loader while it's still connecting or parsing and onec it's done you process your stuff in onPostExecute. There you can disable the loaders view and execute or run your new activity/fragment.

Comment: Should I execute all of the client-side validation first and then the server-side validation. I am currently checking `if (mCurrentPassword != null && passwordsMatch(mCurrentPassword))`. For example, should I call the `changePassword` method after all the server-side validation is successful? i.e. in the `onPostExecute` method (or in my case, the `done` method).

Comment: the best approach (to be sure) is that you don't transfer the password the plain way. hash it somehow (md5, sha1, whatever) and transfer it to the server and do the validation there. Send a hashed string back and then verify if it matches the local hash.

Comment: Unfortunatley, the Parse API does not give access to hashed (or plaintext) passwords for security reasons. So this is not an option.